# CSHTML. Need to make sure field(s) are entered

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The application is a Web MVC application in C#.  When the user is editing a record and clicks on a checkbox I want to make sure 3 fields are filled in.

On the controller I have created a clientside script which is called checkfields:

```
checkBoxProperties.ClientSideEvents.CheckedChanged = 
    "function (s,e) { checkfields(); }";
```

On the CSHTML I have

```
function checkfields() 
{
    alert("Value Empty");
    return false;

}
```

When I check the checkbox I am getting the alert pop up but how do I reference the model fields and popup alert if one of the fields are empty.

Comment: have you considered using unobtrusive validation?

Comment: Is there syntax with unobtrusive validation where you can make a field required with an if condition.  For example if they select the checkbox where it indicates range and then there is a text box where Range1 and another TextBox where Range2 needs to be filled in.  I am using this validation to make model fields required but do not know if you can do this based on another field.

Comment: Use a [foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) `[RequiredIfTrue]` or similar conditional validation attribute applied to your properties so that you get both client and server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use JQuery to select each checkbox and query if it has been checked.

[How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/how-do-i-check-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-jquery)

```js
$("#myCheckBox").on("click", function () {
if ($("#myCheckBox").is(':checked')) {
```

Now you can show a hidden message (show a hidden label, for example), do a popup, or whatever.

Comment: That would work to trigger function when RangeCheckBox is clicked but if they click that I need to make sure Range1 and Range2 are not null or else the user need to enter those values before they enable Range.